# Racket - Picking a random element from a list

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I'm not sure how to make this code work, its so late here that I think my brain has stopped functioning, anyone care to give me a hand?

**The code so far:**

```
(define maze-size 15)
(define-struct Cell (x y))

; adjacents : Cell -> list-of-Cells
; Produce a list of the four Cells above, below, left, and right of 'cell'.

(define(adjacents cell x y)
(list
(make-Cell x (+ y 1))
(make-Cell x (- y 1))
(make-Cell (- x 1) y)
(make-Cell (+ x 1) y)))
```

**Here is where I am getting stumped, how do I fix this?**
Note: The code below does not work.

```
; random-adjacent : list-of-Cells -> Cell
; Produce a random Cell adjacent to a random Cell from the non-empty list'cells'.

(define (random-adjacent cells)
(random (adjacents cell)))
```

**This is what it should behave like:**

```
(check-expect (member? (random-adjacent (list (make-Cell 123 104)))
                   (list (make-Cell 123 105)
                         (make-Cell 123 103)
                         (make-Cell 122 104)
                         (make-Cell 124 104)))
          #true)
```

Comment: There's no need to bump a question, that doesn't work on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This passes your tests:

```scm
(define-struct Cell (x y))

(define (adjacents cell)
  (list
   (make-Cell (Cell-x cell) (+ (Cell-y cell) 1))
   (make-Cell (Cell-x cell) (- (Cell-y cell) 1))
   (make-Cell (- (Cell-x cell) 1) (Cell-y cell))
   (make-Cell (+ (Cell-x cell) 1) (Cell-y cell))))

(define (random-adjacent cell)
  (let ((neighbors (adjacents cell)))
    (list-ref neighbors (random (length neighbors)))))

(check-expect (member? (random-adjacent (make-Cell 123 104))
                       (list (make-Cell 123 105)
                             (make-Cell 123 103)
                             (make-Cell 122 104)
                             (make-Cell 124 104)))
              #true)
```

Comment: is there any way I can email you for further questions?

Comment: That won't be necessary. I'm having a look at this site on a regular basis, and other people could help you just as well or better when I'm not available. Unless we agree on an appropriate hourly rate ;-) Just joking of course.